# Openlayers data label getting overlapped

Tags: label, openlayers, openstreetmap, overlap, overlapping

I am trying to fix the overlapping in data labels. I want to create a gap between data labels when they overlap each other. I have the following code snippet but it's not working as expected. Any follow up suggestions on this?

```
updateDataPointLabel: function (dataPoint, labelConfig) {
                var dataPointStyleArray = [], imageSize = '', iconAnchor = '', alarmHeight = 0, alarmWidth = 0, labelUpdated = 0, labelConfiguration = '', labelConfigObj = '', labelConfigData = '';
                var dataPointObj = dataPoint.get('data');
                var dataPointStyle = dataPoint.get("isHidden") ? dataPoint.get('visibleStyle') : dataPoint.getStyle();
                dataObj.push(dataPointObj);
                if (Array.isArray(dataPointStyle)) {
                    imageSize = dataPointStyle[dataPointStyle.length - 1].getImage().getSize();
                    iconAnchor = dataPointStyle[dataPointStyle.length - 1].getImage().getAnchor();
                }
                else {
                    imageSize = dataPointStyle.getImage().getSize();
                    iconAnchor = dataPointStyle.getImage().getAnchor();
                }
                var minZoom = markerInstances[dataPointObj.markerId].minZoom;
                if (dataPointObj.alarmCount) {
                    if (dataPointObj.alarmCount > 99) {
                        alarmHeight = 7;
                        alarmWidth = 7;
                        if (dataPointStyle == 8) {
                            alarmHeight = 7;
                            alarmWidth = 8;
                        }
                        if (dataPointStyle == 9) {
                            alarmHeight = 5;
                            alarmWidth = 8;
                        }
                        if (dataPointStyle == 10 || dataPointStyle == 11) {
                            alarmHeight = 3;
                            alarmWidth = 14;
                        }
                        if (dataPointStyle == 13) {
                            alarmHeight = 5;
                            alarmWidth = 12;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        alarmHeight = 5;
                        alarmWidth = 5;
                        if (dataPointStyle == 9) {
                            alarmHeight = 3;
                        }
                        if (dataPointStyle == 10 || dataPointStyle == 11) {
                            alarmHeight = 3;
                            alarmWidth = 8;
                        }
                        if (dataPointStyle == 11) {
                            alarmHeight = 3;
                            alarmWidth = 12;
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (var k = 0; k < dataPointObj.dataPointLabels.length; k++) {
                    labelUpdated = 0, labelConfiguration = '';
                    labelConfigObj = dataPointObj.dataPointLabels[k];
                    // check DB configuration is attribute is not provided in push
                    labelConfigData = ({
                        labelId: labelConfigObj.labelId ? labelConfigObj.labelId : 0,
                        dataPointId: dataPointObj.pointId,
                        font: labelConfigObj.font ? labelConfigObj.font : 'Arial',
                        fontColor: labelConfigObj.fontColor ? labelConfigObj.fontColor : 'black',
                        fontSize: labelConfigObj.fontSize ? labelConfigObj.fontSize : 12,
                        fontWeight: labelConfigObj.fontWeight ? labelConfigObj.fontWeight : 'normal',
                        labelId: labelConfigObj.labelId,
                        labelText: labelConfigObj.labelText ? labelConfigObj.labelText : '',
                        minZoom: labelConfigObj.minZoom ? labelConfigObj.minZoom : minZoom,
                        offsetX: labelConfigObj.offsetX ? labelConfigObj.offsetX : 0,
                        offsetY: labelConfigObj.offsetY ? labelConfigObj.offsetY : 0,
                        textAlign: labelConfigObj.textAlign ? labelConfigObj.textAlign : 'Right'
                    });

                    var labelOverlap = false;
                    dataObj.push(dataPointObj);
                    var labelOverlapThreshold = 10; // Adjust the desired gap distance here
                    for (let i = 0; i < dataObj.length; i++) {
                        const dataPoint1 = dataObj[i];
                        const { latitude: lat1, longitude: lng1 } = dataPoint1;
                        const labelTextLength1 = dataPoint1.dataPointLabels[k].labelText.length;
                        const textAlign1 = dataPoint1.dataPointLabels[k].textAlign;
                        const coord1 = [lat1, lng1];
                        var area1 = calculateLabelSize(dataObj[i].dataPointLabels[k].labelText, labelConfig[0])

                        for (let j = i + 1; j < dataObj.length; j++) {
                            const dataPoint2 = dataObj[j];
                            const { latitude: lat2, longitude: lng2 } = dataPoint2;
                            const labelTextLength2 = dataPoint2.dataPointLabels[k].labelText.length;
                            const textAlign2 = dataPoint2.dataPointLabels[k].textAlign;
                            const coord2 = [lat2, lng2];
                            var area2 = calculateLabelSize(dataObj[j].dataPointLabels[k].labelText, labelConfig[0])
                            console.log("size", area2);
                            console.log("area", area2.area);

                            // Calculate the distance between the label centers
                            var distance = calculateDistance(coord1, coord2);

                            // Check if the labels overlap
                            if (distance < area1.width + area2.width + labelOverlapThreshold) {
                                // Labels overlap, calculate a new position with a gap
                                var offsetX = 0;
                                var offsetY = 0;

                                // Adjust the position based on the label alignment
                                if (textAlign1 === 'left' && textAlign2 === 'right') {
                                    offsetX = -(area1.width + area2.width + labelOverlapThreshold);
                                } else if (textAlign1 === 'right' && textAlign2 === 'right') {
                                    offsetX = area1.width + area2.width + labelOverlapThreshold;
                                } else if (textAlign1 === 'center' && textAlign2 === 'center') {
                                    offsetX = (area1.width + area2.width + labelOverlapThreshold) / 2;
                                } else {
                                    offsetX = area1.width + labelOverlapThreshold;
                                }

                                //// Apply the new position to the second label
                                dataPoint2.dataPointLabels[k].offsetX += offsetX;
                                //dataPoint2.dataPointLabels[k].offsetY += offsetY;
                            }
                        

                        }
                    }
                    function calculateDistance(coord1, coord2) {
                        var lat1 = coord1[0];
                        var lng1 = coord1[1];
                        var lat2 = coord2[0];
                        var lng2 = coord2[1];

                        var dx = lng2 - lng1;
                        var dy = lat2 - lat1;

                        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                    }


                    if (labelConfig) {
                        for (var y = 0; y < labelConfig.length; y++) {
                            if (dataPointObj.dataPointLabels[k].labelId == labelConfig[y].labelId) {
                                labelUpdated = 1;
                                // check DB configuration is attribute is not provided in push
                                labelConfiguration = ({
                                    dataPointId: dataPointObj.pointId,
                                    font: labelConfig[y].font ? labelConfig[y].font : labelConfigData.font,
                                    fontColor: labelConfig[y].fontColor ? labelConfig[y].fontColor : labelConfigData.fontColor,
                                    fontSize: labelConfig[y].fontSize ? labelConfig[y].fontSize : labelConfigData.fontSize,
                                    fontWeight: labelConfig[y].fontWeight ? labelConfig[y].fontWeight : labelConfigData.fontWeight,
                                    labelId: labelConfig[y].labelId,
                                    labelText: labelConfig[y].labelText,
                                    minZoom: labelConfigData.minZoom,
                                    offsetX: labelConfig[y].offsetX ? labelConfig[y].offsetX : labelConfigData.offsetX,
                                    offsetY: labelConfig[y].offsetY ? labelConfig[y].offsetY : labelConfigData.offsetY,
                                    textAlign: labelConfigData.textAlign
                                });

                                dataPointStyleArray.push(new ol.style.Style({
                                    zIndex: 0,
                                    id: labelConfig[y].labelId,
                                    text: formatLabelStyle(labelConfig[y].labelText, minZoom, labelConfiguration, imageSize, iconAnchor, alarmHeight, alarmWidth)
                                }));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (labelUpdated == 0) {
                        dataPointStyleArray.push(new ol.style.Style({
                            zIndex: 0,
                            id: labelConfigData.labelId,
                            text: formatLabelStyle(dataPointObj.dataPointLabels[k].labelText, minZoom, labelConfigData, imageSize, iconAnchor, alarmHeight, alarmWidth)
                        }));
                    }
                }

                if (Array.isArray(dataPointStyle)) {
                    dataPointStyleArray.push(dataPointStyle[dataPoint.getStyle().length - 1]);
                    dataPoint.set('visibleStyle', dataPointStyleArray);

                    if (!dataPoint.get("isHidden")) {
                        dataPoint.setStyle(dataPointStyleArray);
                    }
                    else {
                        dataPoint.setStyle(dataPoint.get("hiddenStyle"));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    dataPointStyleArray.push(dataPointStyle);
                    dataPoint.set('visibleStyle', dataPointStyleArray);

                    if (!dataPoint.get("isHidden")) {
                        dataPoint.setStyle(dataPointStyleArray);
                    }
                    else {
                        dataPoint.setStyle(dataPoint.get("hiddenStyle"));
                    }
                }
            },function calculateLabelSize(label, labelConfig) {
        var divElement = document.createElement("span");
        divElement.textContent = labelConfig.labelText;
        divElement.style = "font-size: " + labelConfig.fontSize + "px; font-weight: " + labelConfig.fontWeight + "; color: " + labelConfig.fontColor + "; font-family: " + labelConfig.font + "; white-space: nowrap;"
        document.body.appendChild(divElement);
        var labelWidth = divElement.offsetWidth;
        var labelHeight = divElement.offsetHeight;
        var labelArea = labelWidth * labelHeight;
        document.body.removeChild(divElement);

        return {
            label: label,
            width: labelWidth,
            height: labelHeight,
            area: labelArea
        };
    }
```

I have tried calculating the area, height and width of the label to figure out where they overlap. But can't able to fix it. Tried to add gap by fixing the offset of labels

Comment: You need distance between labels in pixels, which will need view resolution or getPixelFromCoordinate somewhere in the calculation.  If you are trying to reproduce Mapbox's variable placement https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/optimize-map-label-placement/#label-density you could use an array of styles together with the declutter option in OpenLayers as in https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-label-decluttering-forked-cw8qd4?file=/main.js where red (offset) labels are used instead of the central position if they would overlap with other labels.